# Why is there no subring of the integers modulo 29 isomorphic to the integers modulo 8?

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

I understand that for rings R and S, S contains a subring isomorphic to R if and only if there is an injective ring homomorphism from R to S. But I am unsure of how to proceed from this definition?

Also that for rings to be isomorphic you would instead need a bijection.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If $f$ is such a homorphism, what $f(1)$ ? And $f(1)+...+f(1)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** the additive group of the intergers modulo $29$ is cyclic of prime order and has no proper non-trivial subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The integers mod $29$ is a field, and the integers mod $8$ has nonzero zero divisors.